# How to limit user input to certain string values?

Tags: c++, loops

Sorry if this is a simple question but I am fairly new to C++. Any way I am writing and simple weather station that takes in user input and eventually prints it out. In this specific case, the user is asked to enter in the wind direction with the given options of N, NE, NW....and so on. My question is can I have some sort of loop where if they don't enter those appropriate string values its says "Invalid try again" and does the process over again.

Here is the code:

```
    //Asks the user to input the current wind direction and stores it as    windDirection

    cout << "Please enter the current wind direction(N, NE, NW, S, SE, SW, E, W), then press enter." << endl;

    getline(cin, windDirection);
```

Comment: The answer is "yes". Use a `while` loop until you get valid input.

Comment: Or is this question a subtle suggestion to write code for you?

Comment: @PCLuddite not really, I am curious because I made what I thought was a decent attempt of a while loop but it did not work, so wasn't sure if possible.

Comment: @Christian It might be best to show your attempt. That way we can help you correct it.

Comment: @PCLuddite I actually just got the while loop I posted to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This while loop ending up working for me, thanks for those who helped. It could probably be better but it does the job!

```
    //Asks the user to input the current wind direction and stores it as windDirection
    while (cout << "Please enter the current wind direction(N, NE, NW, S, SE, SW, E, W), then press enter." << endl &&
                cin >> windDirection && windDirection != "N" && windDirection != "NE" && windDirection != "NW" && windDirection != "S"
                && windDirection != "SE" && windDirection != "SW" && windDirection != "E" && windDirection != "W"){

     cout << "That is an Invalid wind direction input, try again.\n";
     cin.clear(); 
     cin.ignore();
            }
```